# Handshake error occurs when trying to update a package

Tags: apt, updates

I get the following output when running `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Ign https://repo.varnish-cache.org trusty Release   
Ign https://repo.varnish-cache.org trusty/varnish-4.0 amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign https://repo.varnish-cache.org trusty/varnish-4.0 i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign https://repo.varnish-cache.org trusty/varnish-4.0 Translation-en_US        
Ign https://repo.varnish-cache.org trusty/varnish-4.0 Translation-en           
Err https://repo.varnish-cache.org trusty/varnish-4.0 amd64 Packages           
  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
Err https://repo.varnish-cache.org trusty/varnish-4.0 i386 Packages            
  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
Fetched 5,403 kB in 10s (506 kB/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/dists/trusty/varnish-4.0/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed

W: Failed to fetch https://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/dists/trusty/varnish-4.0/binary-i386/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What does it mean and how do I fix this?

Comment: try `ping google.com` from terminal to confirm that your network is ok!

Comment: Network is fine. Everything else updates ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an ssl error.

If you go to the home page you get:

> repo.varnish-cache.org is no more.
>
> The project homepage has full details about where to obtain releases,
>   packages etc.

If you then go to the home page : http://varnish-cache.org/releases/

You will see

> Deb and RPM repositories now at Packagecloud
>
> The official packages for Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS and Red Hat are now
>   located in repositories at Packagecloud.io. Users of
>   repo.varnish-cache.org repositories will have to change their hosts
>   over to the new repository configuration. For details see the below
>   sections for the distribution in question.

And going through the page evventually leads to

https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish5/install

So , bottom line, you have an ssl error as the repo no longer exists and you need to update your repos ;)

Comment: I have got deb https://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/ trusty varnish-4.0
in my list file. Can I just replace it with something else or do I need to uninstall varnish & then re-install?

Comment: No as you can see that is the wrong repo. See https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish5/install#manual and the link I gave you for details.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ran the varnish 4 install script. I didn't realise I would need to run this. I also manually deleted the old .list file.

Answer (score 5):

To fix, remove **old** Varnish-Cache and broken APT repo source:

`sudo apt-get purge varnish`

`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnish*`

`sudo apt-key list | grep "varnish"`

^ (find the GPG 'KeyID' on the left that matches varnish-cache)

`sudo apt-key del (Varnish-Cache GPG KeyID from above)`

Run apt update - you should see no more errors:

`sudo apt-get update`

---

If you wish to install it again via official Ubuntu repo:

`sudo apt-get install varnish`

See: https://varnish-cache.org/releases/install_debian.html

If you wish to install newest or dev version, follow this (or newer guide):

=> https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish5/install#bash-deb

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04. I had this...

```bsh
curl -s https://syncthing.net/release-key.txt | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/syncthing.list
printf "Package: *\nPin: origin apt.syncthing.net\nPin-Priority: 990\n" | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/syncthing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y syncthing
```

... which gave me this error...

```
W: Failed to fetch https://apt.syncthing.net/dists/syncthing/stable/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
```

The only thing I needed to do was change the `https://apt.syncthing.net/` to `http://apt.syncthing.net/` so it used http instead of https. This is less secure but it's a quick fix for installing packages when you're using old systems like Ubuntu 14.04 that don't have all the latest https ciphers that certain newer APT repos expect clients to use.